# Cumulative distribution of first success in bernoulli trials with p = 0.5

Tags: probability-distributions

A box contains a very large number of balls, so that the probability of choosing a white or red (initially at equal numbers) remains at 1/2 as balls are chosen. Let X be the number of balls chosen at random until a red ball is chosen. Determine the cumulative probability distribution of X.

I've tried with the idea that this might be a geometric progression, so the cumulative function will have p*(1-p)^k for the kth term, and p = 0.5, and summed that from 1->x to give a cumulative distribution function of 1-2^(-n). However, I'm not sure this is correct...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Note first that the cdf $F_X(x)$ of $X$ is equal to $0$ if $x\lt 1$. Now suppose that $x\ge 1$.  Let $\lfloor x\rfloor$ be the greatest integer which is $\le x$.  We have 
$$F_X(x)=\Pr(X\le x)=\Pr(X\le \lfloor x\rfloor)=1-\Pr(X\gt \lfloor x\rfloor).$$
But the probability that $X\gt \lfloor x\rfloor$ is the probability of $\lfloor x\rfloor$ white balls in a row, which is $\frac{1}{2^{\lfloor x\rfloor}}$. Thus
$$F_X(x)=1-\frac{1}{2^{\lfloor x\rfloor}}$$
if $x\ge 1$.

**Remark:** Your answer is along the right lines. However, the cdf $F_X(x)$ is defined for **all** real values of $x$.